# How to count selected radio button in jsp?

Tags: javascript, java, count, radio-button

I am trying to make an online examination system. Questions have been added successfully and even the examiner is getting all the questions with radio options. However m having problem in counting the correct answer. In table, questions along with 4 options and a correct answer is given and m unable to count correct answer. Please suggest me how to do it.
Here is my code:

java.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <body id="processed">
    <% 
            String ques=request.getParameter("ques");
            String op1=request.getParameter("op1");
            String op2=request.getParameter("op2");
            String op3=request.getParameter("op3");
            String op4=request.getParameter("op4");
            String correct=request.getParameter("correct");
            String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
            String dbName = "oes";
            String userId = "root";
            String password = "123456789";
            
            try {
                Class.forName(driverName);
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Connection connection = null;
            Statement st = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
        %>
                        
        <div class="container2">
            <div class="container6">
                <form class="test" action="test.jsp" method="post">
                    <div class="container7">
                        <h1>Java Programming Language</h1><br><br>
                                 
                        <%
                            try{
                                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oes","root","123456789");
                                st= con.createStatement();
                                String sql ="select * from java";
                                rs= st.executeQuery(sql);
                                int i=1;
                                while(rs.next())
                                {
                        %>
                                  
                                    <table class="outertable">
                                        <tr><b><%=i%> <%=rs.getString("ques") %></b>
                                            <td><table class="innertable">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><input type="radio" id="op1" name="radio<%=i%>" value="<%=rs.getString("op1")%>"><%=rs.getString("op1") %></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><input type="radio" id="op2" name="radio<%=i%>" value="<%=rs.getString("op2")%>"><%=rs.getString("op2") %></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><input type="radio" id="op3" name="radio<%=i%>" value="<%=rs.getString("op3")%>"><%=rs.getString("op3") %></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><input type="radio" id="op4" name="radio<%=i%>" value="<%=rs.getString("op4")%>"><%=rs.getString("op4") %></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table></td>
                                        </tr>  
                                    </table>
                        <%      
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="submitbtn">
                       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body id="processed">
        <%
            String st[]=new String[10];
            for(int i=0;i<st.length;i++){
                int j=i+1;
                st[i]=request.getParameter("radio"+j);
                System.out.println(st[i]);
            }
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oes","root", "123456789");
            Statement stmt=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select correct from java");
            String ans="";
            while(rs.next()){
                ans+=rs.getString("correct")+" ";
            }
            int count=0;
            String answers[]=ans.split(" ");
            for(int i=0;i<answers.length;i++){
                if(st[i].equals(answers[i])){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            out.println("Your "+count+" answers are correct");
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You question is not clear. What do you mean you are not able to count correct answer? From your snippet it looks like you have shown question and answer choices in radio buttons. For capturing user response you need to add code in test.jsp to capture radio(i) value in backend and compare with correct answer you have in backend. I hope this helps.

Comment: i have code in test.jsp where m trying to compare the selected answer with correct one but however m not able to do so or my code is not working
here is my test.jsp

Comment: Code is little messy but it seems correct. Try to print st and answers values. Check if case is correct and there is no space. Try comparing after trim and ignoring case.